# Сбой при установке DirectX

Tags: windows, установка, directx

При установке DirectX выскакивает:

> сбой загрузки, несовместимое приложение.

Не грузится ни с диска, ни с флеш-накопителя.

---

Операционная система: Windows 7. Сети нет.

Comment: И ещё, кстати, вопросы принято формулировать на русском языке и по-человечески.

Answer (score 1):

А у вас оффлайн инсталятор?Вот отсюда скачайте и попробуйте [DirectX](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8109)